# Calling other function in the same controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I've this controller, and the `function read($q)` return error `Call to undefined function sendRequest()`

```
<?php

class InstagramController extends BaseController {

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Home Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
| based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
| get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
|
|   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
|
*/

public function read($q)
{
    $client_id = 'ea7bee895ef34ed08eacad639f515897';

    $uri = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$q.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id;
    return sendRequest($uri);
}

public function sendRequest($uri){
    $curl = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}

}
```

I'm assuming it's because I'm referencing the function in the wrong manner, but I can't find any explanations for how to do it.

Comment: You probably want to make sendRequest protected.

Comment: If you call an member var in php you do that with $this-> . And in your function read you call the function sendRequest without $this. Try: return  $this->sendRequest($url);

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Try:

```
return $this->sendRequest($uri);
```

Since PHP is not a pure object-oriented language, it interprets `sendRequest()` as an attempt to invoke a globally defined function (just like `nl2br()` for example), but since your function is part of a class (`InstagramController`), you need to use `$this` to point the interpreter in the right direction.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren I suggest you read more on OOP. $this refers to the current InstagramController object, which has the sendRequest() method on it.

Comment: Becous `sendRequest()` is a function inside class. It's basic use in PHP. Read more about `class`.

Comment: PHP interprets `sendRequest` as an attempt to invoke a globally defined function (just like `nl2br()` for example), but since you defined your `function` inside of a `class` ('InstagramController'), you need to use `$this` to point the interpreter in the right direction.

Comment: PHP is different from C or Java, where you would do as your original post. I think you're assuming it works the same because the language/syntax looks similar in many other ways.

Comment: Worked just fine! However how do I concatenate the outputs of two functions? I tried to show contents from `getTitle` and `getContent` in the following way: `return $this->getTitle() . $this->getContent()` inside another function called `getContent()` which gave me error.

Answer (score 21):

Yes. Problem is in wrong notation. Use:

```
$this->sendRequest($uri)
```

Instead. Or

```
self::staticMethod()
```

for static methods. Also read this for getting idea of OOP - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 2):

You can call the method with `$this->methodNameYouWantToCall($thing_you_want_to_pass)`.

In Your case you can something like this......

```
return $this->sendRequest($uri);
```

Answer (score -2):

To call a function inside a same controller in any laravel version follow as bellow

```
$role = $this->sendRequest('parameter');
// sendRequest is a public function
```

Comment: Is there anything new you want to add? There are two other answers, both years old, giving the same advice