# How to call a function within the same controller?

Tags: oop, soap, controller, wsdl, laravel-5.1

I have to call a soap service using laravel and done so correctly. This soap service requires me to send a login request prior to sending any other request.

The code I'm using works, but I want to improve by removing the login from all the functions and creating one function.
I tried changing the following for one function:

```
public function getcard($cardid)
{
SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
   $service
   ->name('IS')
   ->wsdl(app_path().'\giftcard.wsdl')
   ->trace(true);
 });
$data = [
     'UserName' => 'xxxx',
     'Password'   => 'xxxx',
    ];
$card = [
     'CardId' => $cardid,
     ];
SoapWrapper::service('IS', function ($service) use ($data,$card) {
$service->call('Login', [$data]);
$cardinfo=$service->call('GetCard', [$card]);
dd($cardinfo->Card);
});
}
```

Into:

```
public function login()
{
SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
    $service
    ->name('IS')
    ->wsdl(app_path().'\giftcard.wsdl')
    ->trace(true);
});
$data = [
     'UserName' => 'xxxx',
     'Password'   => 'xxxx',
    ];
SoapWrapper::service('IS', function ($service) use ($data) {
return $service->call('Login', [$data]);
//$service->call('Login', [$data]);
//return $service;
});
}

public function getcard($cardid)
{
$this->login();
$card = [
     'CardId' => $cardid,
    ];
$cardinfo=$service->call('GetCard', [$card]);
dd($card);
}
```

But this doesn't work. I also tried it with the commented out part, but that doesn't work. Both options result in an error that it didn't find 'service'.
I know it has something to do with oop, but don't know any other option.

I took [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861412/calling-other-function-in-the-same-controller) as an example, but I probably implemented it wrong?

So my question is: How do I reuse the login part for all other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement in the `login()` method is within the scope of that closure.  You need to return the result of the closure as well.

```
return SoapWrapper::service('IS', function ($service) use ($data) {
     return $service->call('Login', [$data]);
});
```

**EDIT:**
To explain a little bit.  You have a function:

`SoapWrapper::service('IS' ,function() {}`

Inside of a function : `public function login()`

If you need to return data from your `login()` method, and that data is contained within your `SoapWrapper::service()` method, then both methods need a `return` statement