# Can I use return to a public function in controller in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I got an error which is undefined function.

I tried to use a public function in `return`:

```
public function CreateForm()   //This the function that I want to use back
{
 
    $names2 = DB::table('pendaftaran')
    ->where('isActive',0)
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->get();

    return view('contact')->with($variables);
}
```

So this a function I want to return to a function

```
public function AddUserSubmit(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'Nama'=>'required',
        'NoKP'=>'required',
       
    ]);
    Pendaftaran::create($request->all());


    return CreateForm();   //Can I return to a public function ?
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI on the formatting of your question; use backticks instead of single quotes for formatting code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should work but you need to add context and use the `$this` keyword otherwise `return CreateForm();` will be interpreted as trying to invoke a global function.

Try replacing:

```
return CreateForm();
```

With

```
return $this->CreateForm();
```

See this other question for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861505/4517964